# Making perl's .pm file as .exe file

Tags: perl

I am trying to make my demo1.pm file executable(.exec). I am trying to build it using following code -

Build.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl  
use strict;
use warnings;
use Module::Build;

use 5.22.1;

my $builder = Module::Build->new(
    module_name         => 'demo1',
    license             => 'perl',
    create_makefile_pl  => 0,     #'traditional',
    script_files        => 'Demo/demo1.pm',
    create_readme       => 0,
    requires            =>       {
        'File::Basename'      => '0',
    },
);

$builder->create_build_script();
```

I am running above code as -

```
perl Build.pl
```

But that's not working and throwing below error -

```
Can't find file lib/demo1.pm to determine version at /usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1/Module/Build/Base.pm line 1196.
```

Can anyone help me to achieve the aim, please? Thanks in advance

Comment: 1) Module::Build doesn't create .exe files. 2) It expects the module named to be in `lib/`, not `Demo/` 3) Lower-cased module names are used to indicate a pragma module. You shouldn't call your module `Demo1.pm`, not `demo1.pm`.

Comment: To make an executable, you first need a script (often `.pl` file) which uses the module and executes code when invoked. Modules are not meant to be invoked directly, only via scripts. To create an `exe` from your script, try [PAR Packer](https://metacpan.org/pod/pp).